# Using convert options for ImageMagick in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Working on a project that will allow conversion of an uploaded pdf to png. Here's what I've got so far:

```
 class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

          has_attached_file :attachment1, 
             styles: { image: ["1125x1500", :png] }, 
             default_url: "/images/missing.png", 
             :convert_options => { density: "1050", quality: "1050" }

{other stuff}
end
```

The `convert_options` doesn't seem to be working, as adjusting the density and quality seem to make no changes in the image.  I fear I'm not using correct syntax here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convert_options uses the key as the image style, and the value is the string of options:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment1, 
     styles: { image: ["1125x1500", :png] }, 
     default_url: "/images/missing.png", 
     :convert_options => { image: "-density 1050 -quality 1050" }

  {other stuff}
end
```

Comment: Note: I'm assuming you know the quality level here is nonsensical, just keeping the example consistent.  Quality should be 1-100